# Image does not scale properly in Phonegap, jQuery mobile application

Tags: css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm creating an iPhone app using PhoneGap and jQuery mobile. I'm using a simple image tag and set the width to 100% and height to auto, but the image is not scaling properly and gets cut off. I have also tried using max-width with the same outcome. Any idea how I can solve this?

```
<div data-role="page">
    <img class="banner" src="..." style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
</div>
```

I have even tried this:

```
$('img.banner').each(function(){
    $(this).width($(window).width());                      
});
```

Comment: Are you using a meta `viewport` tag? If not then try something like this: `<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">`. You can also use this meta tag to limit the amount that users can zoom in/out on your site.

Comment: I'm using that actually: <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in a plain JQM page (without phonegap)?

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. I just removed the reference to cordova.js and the image still looks cut off.

Comment: @farjam I tried to reproduce it in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/apaveh/1/edit) and I don't see what your referring to, is it possible you have some other css that might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Previously i have gone through same problem. I tried min-height. And why both  `maximum-scale=1`, `minimum-scale=1`? Try `minimum-scale=1`. Just give a try

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I did what you said, but still the image looks cut off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your image is actually nested in a div with a `data-role="content"` and your problem is that class `ui-content` by default has a 15px padding.

The simplest way to correct that would be to simply override the CSS for that page to get rid of that padding, if you need it for other elements then just wrap them in a div and add padding to those divs.

For example

CSS

```
.imgContPage { padding:0px; }
```

Markup

```
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content" class="imgContPage">
    <img class="banner" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.png&text=PlaceHolder" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Link to [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/apaveh/1/)

Alternatively you can set a negative margin on your `img` to compensate for the padding, but then you will need to calculate the width so that it fills up to the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I feel very stupid right now. I was getting that image from a JSON response that was coming from a Wordpress website. When I was parsing my JSON to get to the image, I was using the thumbnail version of the image (which in my surprise, it's not really a scaled thumbnail, it's just a cropped 150x150 square of the main image).

So I changed my reference from:

```
json.page.thumbnail
```

to

```
json.page.attachments[0].images.full.url
```

And now the image scales just fine (width: 100%, height: auto).

Thanks everyone for your helps

Comment: The best thing to do is delete the question, since it's not really a valid one anymore.

Comment: I tried to but since there is a bounty set for this question, SO doesn't let me delete it.

Comment: No worries, maybe try once the bounty has been awarded. I'm glad you figured out your issue though.